# Extracting data from other methods in java and finding proper return types

Tags: java, arrays, methods, types, return

I am going to explain this as best I can.. I have a user input data in the main to add information. It goes through the bankparser class to split up the data which inevitably passes through a third class irrelevant to this code. However, I get an error when trying to print the banks. I am 95% positive it is because my return in the BankParser class is null. I am not sure what return type it requires since the type is actually another class. Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks!

I want the output when I print the bank information to look something like this: 
Bank name:      BankName
Bank ID:        12345
Bank address:       Boston, MA

MAIN

---

```
case 'A':   //Add Bank
           System.out.print("Please enter the bank information:\n");
           inputInfo = scan.nextLine();
           bank1 = BankParser.bankParser(inputInfo);
           accounts[index] = bank1;
           index++;
           break;
         case 'B':   //Display banks
           for (int i=0; i< index; i++)
                    System.out.print(accounts[i].toString());
           break;
```

BankParser

---

```
public class BankParser {

public static Bank bankParser(String lineToParse)
{
    Address AddressSetter = new Address();
    Bank BankSetter = new Bank();

    //Take in user data and segregate by bankName/bankID/city,state

    String bankInfo = lineToParse;

    String[] bankInfoArray = lineToParse.split("/"); //split array data

    String bankName = bankInfoArray[0];
    String bankID = bankInfoArray[1];
    String bankCity = bankInfoArray[2];
    String bankState = bankInfoArray[3];

    AddressSetter.setCity(bankCity);
    AddressSetter.setState(bankState);
    BankSetter.setBankAddress(bankCity, bankState);
    BankSetter.setBankID(bankID);
    BankSetter.setBankName(bankName);

    System.out.println(bankInfoArray[0]);


    return null;








}
```

}

Comment: Please post your stacktrace.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Assignment4.main(Assignment4.java:47)

Comment: Since your `bankParser` method have as return value `Bank`, you must return an instance of `Bank` class created inside the method (or a field of the class). Maybe you want to return `BankSetter`. I would also recommend you to follow Java conventions. Your variables should be called `bankSetter` and `addressSetter`.

Comment: line 47 refers to System.out.print(accounts[i].toString());

Comment: Christian, when I return BankSetter and then print the list of account s in the main, it only shows the city and state because the AddressSetter is passed through the toString method in the main. How can I get all of the data to show up?

Comment: @user2875661, please click the `edit` button above to add this information to your original post. Also, your above files go by different names, so please indicate which file is `Assignment4.java` and where about line 47 is.

Answer (score 0):

The bankParser method header says it should return a Bank class object, but it is set to return null

Trying to call that and save the result will always give you a null there.
Based on this line in BankParser, it looks like it is used to print itself

```
System.out.println(bankInfoArray[0]);
```

Comment: That sysout line was for a test to make sure the data was being split into different parts, I actually deleted it and it is not needed in my code.

Comment: Why is AddressSetter a separate class? is it setting the address attributes for the Bank class?

Comment: It's not a separate class. It's an object.

Comment: How does Address relate to Bank?  It isn't printing the address because the bankParse method only returns a Bank object.